# How to set my WSL account to use the group "Domain Users" (the one my Windows account uses)

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Normally when I look (in WSL) at the files and directories created by my Windows account, they show up as:

```
 -rwxrwxrwx+ 1 cfclark Domain Users    2858 Mar 26 16:28 yy_myref.h
```

However, if I do things in WSL to the file (edit with Emacs, checkout with git, run programs that write these file, etc.) the permissions get changed to:

```
 -rwxrwx---+ 1 cfclark cfclark         2858 Mar 26 16:28 yy_myref.h
```

Moreover, then WSL refuses to read the file, like it thinks it is somehow "other".

I already have 'umask 0' in my .bashrc file.  I haven't done anything special to mount the partition, e.g. I have no wsl.config file.

For a temporary workaround I keep a cygwin shell running and in it run

```
find /cygdrive/r/directory-path -exec chown "cfclark:Domain Users" {} \;
find /cygdrive/r/directory-path -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Note, the equivalent find commands don't work in WSL.  It cannot find the files to make the relevant changes.

And, yes, I know the risks of running such an open system.  However, it is my personal single user laptop and I don't care.  But having my test runs create files that I can't compare to my known results without an intervening step is too much of a pain.  It the permissions were -rw-rw-rw-, I would be ok with that.

I assume that if I get the "group" fixed, the permissions will also get fixed.  However, fixing the permissions alone (without running a script) would be sufficient.